# eval() on string replacement | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, eval

Is it possible that an array of string replacements using regex can use `eval` to execute and return a value from a function which I need to be done via this method:

```
var message = $('#message').html();

var searchstring = [
    /<span style="color: rgb((.*), (.*), (.*));">(.*)<\/span>/gi,
    // other regex
];

var replacestring = [
    eval('RGBtoHex($1, $2, $3)'),
    // other regex
];

for(i = 0; i < searchstring.length; i++)
{
    message = message.replace(searchstring[i], replacestring[i]);
}

$('.message-box').val(message);
```

I'm trying to convert RGB to a hexadecimal value so it should change to something like: `rgb(255, 255, 255)` to `#FFFFFF`. However, when I do this it says in Firebug: `$1 is not defined` which is located for this: `eval('RGBtoHex($1, $2, $3)'),`.

How will I be able to execute an `eval()` function to return rgb to a hexadecimal value while doing string replacements with `.replace()`?

Everything works perfectly except the eval part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. When you call `eval`, you are `eval`ing the raw string `'RGBtoHex($1, $2, $3)'`.

You need to [pass a function to `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```js
message.replace(
    /rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/gi, 
    function(str, r, g, b) { return RGBtoHEX(r, g, b); }
);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I've certainly gave a read on that documentation. Thanks! :) *will vote in 3 minutes*

Comment: I am a bit curious as to your example, where do str, r, g, b com from? I mean say I have this code `var templateString = '<div class="slide" style="background-image:url(|@imageURL|); width:|@width|px;" ></div>';

var regex = /\|@([a-zA-z1-9_]*)\|/g;
var imageURL = 'someImage.jpg';
var width = 500;

var replaceString = templateString.replace(regex, '$1')`
can I somehow eval $1 to get the imageURL value and width value?

Comment: Oh I worked it out=) Still looks like magic but `var replaceString = templateString.replace(regex, 
                                           function(x, y)
                                           { console.log(x); console.log(y); var value = eval(y); return value;} 
                                            );` is exactly what I needed

Comment: @Olga: See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter  The callback takes parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your eval is executed during the creation of the replacement array. Sure you can call code at replacement time by simply passing a function accepting a parameter instead of a substitute string... for example

```
"1234".replace(/\d/g,function(x){return parseInt(x)+1})
```

returns `"2345"` as result